# lvm raid5 used only 3 of the 4 drives in my vg

Tags: raid, lvm

I'm trying to build a (test) raid5 on my raspberry pi with 4 usb drives using lvm2. It is running ubuntu server 20.04, 32bit arm.

Despite putting all 4 drives in the same vg, and then using that vg to create a raid5 lv, it seems only three drives are used for the raid. Why?

Here's what I did:

```
$ sudo vgcreate kingstorevg /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
$ sudo lvcreate --type raid5 -l 100%FREE --nosync -n kingstorelv kingstorevg
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/kingstorevg/kingstorelv
$ sudo mount /dev/kingstore/kingstorelv /mnt/kingstore/

$ sudo vgs
  VG          #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree 
  kingstorevg   4   1   0 wz--n- 231.17g 57.79g

$ df -h
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/kingstorevg-kingstorelv  114G   61M  108G   1% /mnt/kingstore

$ lsblk
NAME                                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                                    8:0    1  57.8G  0 disk 
└─sda1                                 8:1    1  57.8G  0 part 
  ├─kingstorevg-kingstorelv_rmeta_0  253:0    0     4M  0 lvm  
  │ └─kingstorevg-kingstorelv        253:6    0 115.6G  0 lvm  /mnt/kingstore
  └─kingstorevg-kingstorelv_rimage_0 253:1    0  57.8G  0 lvm  
    └─kingstorevg-kingstorelv        253:6    0 115.6G  0 lvm  /mnt/kingstore
sdb                                    8:16   1  57.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1                                 8:17   1  57.8G  0 part 
  ├─kingstorevg-kingstorelv_rmeta_1  253:2    0     4M  0 lvm  
  │ └─kingstorevg-kingstorelv        253:6    0 115.6G  0 lvm  /mnt/kingstore
  └─kingstorevg-kingstorelv_rimage_1 253:3    0  57.8G  0 lvm  
    └─kingstorevg-kingstorelv        253:6    0 115.6G  0 lvm  /mnt/kingstore
sdc                                    8:32   1  57.8G  0 disk 
└─sdc1                                 8:33   1  57.8G  0 part 
  ├─kingstorevg-kingstorelv_rmeta_2  253:4    0     4M  0 lvm  
  │ └─kingstorevg-kingstorelv        253:6    0 115.6G  0 lvm  /mnt/kingstore
  └─kingstorevg-kingstorelv_rimage_2 253:5    0  57.8G  0 lvm  
    └─kingstorevg-kingstorelv        253:6    0 115.6G  0 lvm  /mnt/kingstore
sdd                                    8:48   1  57.8G  0 disk 
└─sdd1                                 8:49   1  57.8G  0 part

$ sudo lvs -a -o name,segtype,devices
  LV                     Type   Devices                                                                
  kingstorelv            raid5  kingstorelv_rimage_0(0),kingstorelv_rimage_1(0),kingstorelv_rimage_2(0)
  [kingstorelv_rimage_0] linear /dev/sda1(1)                                                           
  [kingstorelv_rimage_1] linear /dev/sdb1(1)                                                           
  [kingstorelv_rimage_2] linear /dev/sdc1(1)                                                           
  [kingstorelv_rmeta_0]  linear /dev/sda1(0)                                                           
  [kingstorelv_rmeta_1]  linear /dev/sdb1(0)                                                           
  [kingstorelv_rmeta_2]  linear /dev/sdc1(0)
```

As you can see, `/dev/sdd` is not used in the lv. Why, and how can I fix that?

Comment: What is the output of `lvs -a -o name,segtype,devices`?

Comment: Output added :)

Comment: Darn, I wish I knew more about LVM RAIDs.  I have most of my experience in using the mdadm.  Unfortunately, I would be no help on this one, so that is why you got my +1 for visual.  Hopefully someone coming along might have stumbled into the same thing.

Comment: I'm not restricted to lvm, mind you. This is my first raid ever, and lvm felt like a good choice. But maybe it's just too young? I don't know. Feel free to suggest how you would do it with mdadm :)

Comment: Here's one decent write up on it https://www.golinuxcloud.com/configure-software-raid-5-array-linux/ , but I would change the command to build the array wtih `sudo mdadm -Cv -l5 -c64 -n4 -pls /dev/md0 /dev/sd{a,b,c,d}1` to cover all 4 of your drives.  To check it you can run `cat /proc/mdstat` and you can run `sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0`.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue today. The fix was to specify the number of stripes using -i 3. So, the working command should be:

```
sudo lvcreate -i 3 --type raid5 -l 100%FREE --nosync -n kingstorelv kingstorevg
```

I hope this can help someone in the future.